# How to retrieve a function from a function argument in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I'm stuck in getting a function pointer back from a function parameter.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
int a(int I)
{
    return I*I;
}

void get_a(int(*R)(int))
{
    R = &a;
}

int main()
{
    int(*function)(int) = NULL;

    printf("function a=%p\n", a);

    get_a(function);
    printf("function a=%p\n", &function); // Is never the right address.

    return 0;
}
```

Searching the net did not help, I could only find examples of pass a function as parameter, so I gave up and tried solving this problem by myself.

Comment: This is no different from "how to retrieve an int from a function argument". Solve that problem first, and you'll understand this one, too.

Comment: Your function get_a() does precisely nothing, because all it does is assign to a local variable and then return nothing. A good compiler might even optimize it out entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issue here.

First, your function is modifying a local variable, so the result will never be reflected in the caller.  You need to pass the address of your function pointer variable, then have `get_a` accept a pointer-to-function-pointer.  By passing the variable's address, you can dereference it and modify it.

The second issue is that your second `printf` is printing the *address* of `function` instead of its *value*.  Pass in the value.

```
void get_a(int(**R)(int))
{
    *R = &a;
}

int main()
{
    int(*function)(int) = NULL;

    printf("function a=%p\n", (void *)a);

    get_a(&function);
    printf("function a=%p\n", (void *)function);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
function a=0x400498
function a=0x400498
```

Also note the cast to `void *`.  Passing a pointer to `printf` to be printed via `%p` is one of the rare cases when casting to a `void *` is required, otherwise you could run into undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank for a fast reply with a working example, just what i needed:). Been trying several combinations with extra * and &, but apparently no this one.

Comment: @PuzzlingProgrammer Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: That should be `printf("... %p ...", (void *)whatever)` in both cases, or the behavior is undefined.  (This isn't just because we're dealing with pointers-to-functions; `printf` is variadic, so there is no automatic conversion of pointers; an argument for %p must be cast to `void *` unless its type already is `[const] void *` or (in C11 only) `[const] char *`.)

Comment: @zwol Good catch. Edited.

Comment: Casting a function pointer to void is ub in a strict implementation.

Answer (score 3):

First problem is that you print a pointer to `function` pointer, not its value; it will never give you the right address.

With this issue out of the way, the remaining problem is that `R` is a function pointer passed by value. Any changes to it inside `get_a` are local to the function, and do not reflect in the value of `function` inside `main`.

You have two solutions to this problem:

- make `get_a` return function pointer, and assign `function = get_a()` in the `main`, or
- Pass a pointer to function pointer into `get_a`, and assign with dereference, i.e. use the same technique that you use for non-function pointers.

Here is how you can implement the second approach:

```
void get_a(int(**R)(int)) {
    *R = a;
}
...
get_a(&function);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KdU2AL)

**Note:** ISO C forbids conversion of function pointers to `void*`, which is what is required to print with `%p`. I assume that you are doing it for debugging purposes, though.

Comment: Solution to 1st approach should be `int (*get_a())(int) {return &a;}`. Messy.

Comment: Curious: Does ISO C allow `uintmax_t (or uintptr_t)  p = (cast_to_type) function_ptr'`?  even if the destination type is not wide enough for all of `function_ptr`?

Comment: @chux Good question, I have no idea.

Comment: @chux Only a pointer to void may be converted to uintptr_t, and vice-versa.

Comment: @2501 Thanks for pointing that out.  Yet the conversion  spec for `void*` to/from `uintptr_t` is to maintain _equality_. (round trip).  My comment was wondering if a pointer to any function can be converted (w/o UB) to `uintptr_t` - without regard to its round-trip equivalency.  Perhaps I'll research that more later.

Comment: @chux Yes a function pointer can be converted to an integer (and vice-versa) but the result is implementation-defined (it can be a trap value).

Comment: @2501 Sounds right in _general_, but I do not think a function pointer conversion to `uintptr_t` can result in a trap-value, as in the case of the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663553/how-to-retrieve-a-function-from-a-function-argument-in-c/40663601?noredirect=1#comment68558750_40663601) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663553/how-to-retrieve-a-function-from-a-function-argument-in-c/40663601?noredirect=1#comment68591004_40663601)

Comment: @chux uintptr_t may have padding bits and thus trap representations. I forgot to mention there is also this rule: *If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined.*